# How to Upload Files to Drive using AppsScript and Promises to guarantee that the file was uploaded before getting the file ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

*Sorry for any poor english writing ;(*

I've been struggling to make a file upload function that uses promises for uploading and then returning the ID of the file.

I've been done a couple researches before and many of then worked fine! But when I send the project to Production, it just doesn't work at all.

> What I need: A function that uploads a File to google Drive, then after that it returns the file ID.
> With the file ID I can then later search on Google Drive and use the file as attachments to MailApp.

My code is:

```
function setupFileUrl(fileContent, fileName) {
    let contentType = fileContent.substring(5, fileContent.indexOf(';'));
    let bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(fileContent.substr(fileContent.indexOf('base64,') + 7));
    let file = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, fileName);
    try {
        const addedFile = sendFile(file);
        return [addedFile.getUrl(), addedFile.getId()]
    } catch (e) {
        let logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(appSpreadsheetID).getSheetByName("log");
        logSheet.appendRow([new Date(), user, e, "setupFileUrl at file Creation"]);
        return e
    }

}
```

This is one of many attempts of codes that I made, but all of then are just returning the same issue again and again.

Everyone that tried to upload a file creates a Log on my Log sheet that says:
`Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. Exception: Invalid argument: id`

What I understood is happening, is that the ID is being requested without waiting for the uploading process, so I tried to make it using promises, but the promises are returning an empty object "{}" instead of the ID of the file.

```
function sendFilewithPromise(base64Data, nomeArq) {

    const splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');
    const byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    const ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(nomeArq);

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
    try{
      const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(driveFolderID)
      const file = folder.createFile(ss)
      resolve(file.getId())
    } catch(error){
      reject(error);
    }
   }).then(res => res.getId())
   .then(uploadedFile => {return uploadedFile})
    .catch((e) => {
      let logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(appSpreadsheetID).getSheetByName("log");
      logSheet.appendRow([new Date(), user, e, "setupFileUrl at Reading file ID and URL"]);
      return e
    })
}
```

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: I have 3 questions. 1. How much size is the file when your error occurs? 2. Where does the error `Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. Exception: Invalid argument: id` occurs in your showing script? 3. What is `sendFile` and can you provide the script?

Comment: @Tanaike

1. I have limited the file size to 1 MB maximum

2. The error is ocurring everytime this function is called by the user, they have all the permissions, it also works on all of my tests even with another user that I gave temporary access to test to the project.

3. I'm sorry, but I can't share the whole script because it is used on my work with some sensitive data, but I even when I create a script with only that function and ask for another user to test, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Tanaike
`
function sendFile(file) {
    let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(driveFolderID)
    let addedFile = folder.createFile(file)
    return addedFile
}
`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike No problem, I'm not a native english speaker too :D 

I just need to make this function work, I need a function that uses promises and returns the ID of the file after uploading it.

But when I make a function using promises and make a console.log, it returns an empty object, not the ID of the file on Drive